# Getting the range of an applied span in SpannableString

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I am trying to get the set of applied spans on a `SpannableString` and then find the ranges in which they have been applied. Is that possible? As far as I have seen, there doesn't seem to be a built in method to do this. Am I right?

```
Object[] spans = spannableString.getSpans(0, spannableString.length(), Object.class);

    List<Object> spanArray = asList(spans);

    for (Object span: spanArray) {
        if (span.getClass().equals(MyCustomSpan.class)) {
            MyCustomSpan s = (MyCustomSpan) span;

            // Get the range in spannableString where this span has been applied.
            // How do I do this?
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Call `getSpanStart()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#getSpanStart(java.lang.Object)) and [`getSpanEnd()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spanned.html#getSpanEnd(java.lang.Object)) to retrieve the start and end positions within the `Spanned` where the span is applied.

Comment: Awesome! Worked like a charm. :)